# Jquery Drop down with pages ? Friendly dropdown for touchscreen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, combobox, touch

I was wondering if there is a plugin to display the options of a drop down menu with some sort of pagination. I'm trying to design a friendly form for touch screen devices however my main problem right now are the drop downs.

A picture speaks better than a thousand words so this is what i'm looking for

[image]

Comment: I hate when people divert the focus of the question with side-ways suggestions, but I couldn't resist here: have you considered an alternative user interface? Because this will be a very strange user experience.   I would recommend a dropdown with search/filter capabilities - plenty of plugins to choose from (Select2, Chosen, etc...)

Comment: Yeah i would rather not have a search just because of the typing

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any plugin that does all of what you want, but depending on your jQuery skills, this should be fairly easy to do.

Just create a div with `position: absolute;` positioned exactly below your "Select option dropdown" link. Inside that div you'll place the options you want (I recommend [this plugin](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) to do the "back" and "next" functionalities), and use jQuery's `.toggle()` method to hide/show that absolutely positioned div whenever the user clicks the "Select option dropdown" link.

Comment: Fair enough, i was just hopping to re use instead of developing myself.

Comment: Man, i gave you +1, that plugin is awesome!